# add cascading parameters in ssrs connected to oracle

Tags: oracle, reporting-services

I'm trying to add cascading parameters in SSRS connected to Oracle. Tried using @ but oracle doesn't allow hence used : but after giving it the dependent field starts showing text box instead of drop down. Has anyone handled this kind of scenario before?

Comment: Can anyone please answer?

Answer (score 0):

I used in clause and put the first parameter name with colon

Ex: where emp in (:DEPT_ID)